# Generic Type converting Puzzle

Tags: c#, generics, casting

i have method that its signature looks like

```
public object LoadCache(string cacheName,Type returnType)
```

and from this method another method is called which signature like this

```
 BBCacheProvider.BbCacheProvider.GetCache<T>(string cacheName);
```

is there any way to send returnType parameter as T in the method?

i believe that there is no way to do that! but there must be a way around it!

Comment: Sure its possible. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx

Comment: It's possible, but you will have to use reflection.

Comment: Any reason to not make `LoadCache` generic?

Comment: the point here that we are using wcf and its impossible to pass a generic parameter throw the service. there for we must have a we to pass there type of the cache to load it from the provider. and it takes <T>.and we do not know what T code be until run time. therefor am trying to pass the returntype as parameter and convert it to T :) by the way i do not think that Type.MakeGenericType might help.

Comment: Problem answered at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107845/generics-in-c-using-type-of-a-variable-as-parameter

Comment: If you can't make LoadCache generic, since it returns `object` anyway, can you just use `GetCache<object>`?

Comment: @mao47 actually you might be right, but the point is that T is a known type which will be set at run time from the client side! wcf makes it hard some times :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a similar [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003023/cast-to-generic-type-in-c-sharp)  here which i did change it as needed. so reflection is the hero.

```
public void ClientCacheLoadRerquest(Type tType, string key)
    {
        MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod("GetCache");
        MethodInfo closedMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(tType);
        closedMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { key });
    }
```